# Adding a Varchar auto-increment column to an select query

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, database-design, sql-insert

I'm trying to design a database and I have grouped a certain data as follows

```
select Name, prod_cat, prod_country, count(*)
from table1 
group by Name, prod_cat, prod_country

union

select Name, prod_cat, prod_country, count(*)
from table2 
group by Name, prod_cat, prod_country
```

Now for the resultant data from the query above, I would like to add an auto-increment ID as a `VARCHAR` column which should start as 'U000001' , 'U000002' , 'U000003' , 'U000004' ... all the way to the last column

1. For a better database, is it better to put the resultant query into a temporary table/view or is it better to use a stored procedure as there could be more data coming in
2. How can I add an auto-incrementing `ID VARCHAR` column to the above mentioned select query? Should I use Declare and increment?

Expected result :

| Prod_ID | Name | Prod_cat | Prod_country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| U000001 | abc | 12 | USA |
| U000002 | efg | 1 | IND |
| U000003 | def | 3 | MEX |
| U000004 | ijk | 21 | CHN |